# Birth date of Adi Śankaracharya

Tags: india, indian, ancient-india

When was Sri Ādi Śankaracharya born exactly? In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Adi_Shankara&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#Birth-dates) and [elsewhere](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/government-wrong-on-adi-shankaras-birth-year-kanchi-seer/article7908827.ece) there have been controversial dates, one claiming a birth in the 5th century B.C. and another around A.D.730-780. Why is there so much confusion amongst the different sankara mathas regarding the date of birth?

Comment: Can you post links to those sources? The only date I could dig up with Professor Google was the later one.

Comment: @T.E.D. you can see this link:https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Adi_Shankara&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#Birth-dates, where four different dates are given, also see http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/government-wrong-on-adi-shankaras-birth-year-kanchi-seer/article7908827.ece

Comment: @T.E.D. This reference explains how there is a controversy of 509 BC vs. 788 AD https://books.google.com/books?id=HJFldI75dRcC&pg=PA32&dq=adi+sankaracharya+bc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQs-P_jIvRAhXD7iYKHRqVCV8Q6AEIQjAJ#v=onepage&q=adi%20sankaracharya%20bc&f=false Kanchipuram: Land of Legends, Saints and Temples
By P.V.L. Narasimha Rao

Comment: Actually, if you read the second link, the interviewee is pretty explicit about why he doesn't like accepted date. He casts it as why *everybody else* doesn't like his date, but he's the one trying to argue for a change.

Comment: Furthermore, Sankaracharya is famous for his efforts of reviving spirit of "Hinduism" in India, when it was under Buddhist influence. That would be very much at odds with 5th Century B.C.

Comment: @taninamdar ok, take it for granted that sankaracharya was born at A.D.730-780. But, the main question is why is there so much lack of sufficient evidence and discordance amongst the mathas, when kings like Sriharsha were ruling at that time and several records are now extant. We seem to say so much about ancient India, but in the critical sense, even such facts as birth dates is still refutable seems to be quite confusing.

Comment: This question was asked one of our [forum](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15603/birth-date-of-adi-shankaracharya/18573#18573). The birth date of Sri Ādi Śankaracharya is doubtful.